Appwrite Cloud API returns 'Route Not Found' (404) on valid endpoint
I am trying to use the Appwrite Cloud API in my Next.js project, but I keep encountering the following error:
{
"message": "The requested route was not found. Please refer to the API docs and try again.",
"code": 404,
"type": "general_route_not_found",
"version": "1.6.0"
}
What I am using:
Endpoint: https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1

Appwrite Version: 1.6.0

Environment Variables:
    NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT: https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1
    NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID: my_project_id

Code Example: Here’s how I’m initializing the Appwrite client:

import { Client } from 'appwrite';
const client = new Client();
client
.setEndpoint(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_ENDPOINT) // https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1
.setProject(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPWRITE_PROJECT_ID); // my_project_id
Dependencies:
appwrite@14.0.1
node-appwrite@11.1.1
next@15.0.3
react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106

Verified the endpoint and project ID in the Appwrite dashboard.
Printed the environment variables to confirm they are being loaded correctly.
Tested the API directly using Postman:
The same 404 error occurs.
Checked my Appwrite Cloud project settings and ensured the API key has the necessary permissions.
Reviewed the Appwrite API documentation for the correct endpoints.
